# Parsing the Facebook client string

Tags: c#, facebook, sdk

I just started to read about the Facebook SDK and I want to gets posts from my timeline or whatever to my site.
Problem is:
I get the posts with:

```
var post = client.Get("732642713?fields=posts");
```

and the result is:

```
{"name":"Name","id":"12432236"},"story":"Name is now friends with Name and 6 other.. etc etc.
```

What I want from this string is:

```
Name is now friends with Name and 6 other not the name and stuff.
```

Any ideas?

Comment: This is JSON. Use a JSON parser like [JSON.NET](http://json.codeplex.com/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using the Outercurve C# Facebook SDK, then the `post` variable in your example will be a dynamic object.

As explained on the Outercurve 'Getting started' page (http://facebooksdk.net/docs/web/getting-started/), you can think of the dynamic object as a key-value pair dictionary.

Therefore the value that you want will reside within a `story` property of the dynamic object, which could be accessed thus:

```
string desiredStory = post.story;
```

If on the other hand you're talking about the raw JSON returned by the Facebook endpoints, you can send it through a JSON (de)serializer (such as JSON.Net or ServiceStack.Text) and access the value you want via a standard property from the deserializated object

Comment: Yes it's via the JSON.Net.
But I don't know to change this string or ye, use tje JSON.Net servicestack, but ye thank you I will look it up!

Comment: Do you have any examples for how to parse a via json?